# I made this logo for our college batch named "Gallants". But it looks really off how do I improve it?

Tags: logo, critique, design-principles

So basically the entire premise was to design something around the meaning of the word, i.e., brave/heroic. Hence, I thought of designing it around a shield which are kinda hexagonal, so I went with that. Also, since Lions are a sign of bravery, I added that too. The initial drafts had a caduceus too (since it’s a medical college).

But finally thought it would look too messy. The shadows were inspired from The Phoenix Suns, it looks kinda off, I can't make out why. Would like your thoughts and opinions on improving it.

(The first one is the final design, the other 2 are drafts.)

[image: The Final Logo]

[image: the inital design]

[image: a mockup with the caduceus]

Comment: "Logos" should really be 100% original artwork and not comprised of stock imagery: https://stock.adobe.com/search?k=lion&asset_id=407469987 -- But if it's just a hobby project, no harm. (...and, it's not impossible that you are the Adobe contributor responsible for the stock image.)

Comment: Hello, sorry I didn't mention that yes it's a hobby project kind of thing. The logos won't be used anywhere where there is copyright and money involved and no I'm not the Adobe contributor responsible for the stock image.

Comment: That’s not shield-shaped – shields aren’t hexagonal. It would be more shield-like if the top half were flatter and the bottom half taller, but that would likely reduce legibility. I personally prefer the expression and simplicity of the second, but the reused A doesn’t work (it says ‘Gallints’ or perhaps ‘Gal Lints’), and the caduceus makes it too busy.

Comment: Hey Tanish and welcome. Please edit your question to follow our [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) or you question may be closed

Comment: Couple things: The gaping hole left by the first L is a huge issue visually... and are you women? Because the first word is "gal", but "gallant" generally conveys a more male attribute. Women *can* absolutely be gallant, it's just that the word tends to be more masculine in nature. It's like calling a woman "handsome". Nothing wrong with it, but it's often sensed as a dichotomy. If you *aren't* women then "gal" may be another big issue. You should *never* break a word so that it creates a different, separate word entirely... i.e.  "Nosmo King" as opposed to "No Smoking".

Comment: The name should be one row. The lion should be truculent. It cannot work with  something invisible in the right, it must be turned 90 degrees (there's something). The lion cannot be the iStock demo image I inserted, a competent draughtsman is needed to create something you can freely publish. Beware comics! It must be truculent. Add  a sharp slogan which fits into your goals and principles. Preferably in a  banner. I have only a placeholder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4STp.png Your sturdy lettering style of the name Gallants is better than Palatino text I used.

Comment: @user287001 Why must the lion be truculent, and what does that even mean? The lion in the designs in the question look quite truculent to me. Do you mean affronté – and if so, why? Design-wise, I think the rampant sinister attitude in the OP’s versions works better than the salient(ish) affronté attitude in your version.

Comment: This is only an opinion. and this is my suggestion how to make it effective as I see  what effective means. Truculent = agressively self-assertive. A group in a school cannot be anything else if it's not based on some superior talent, but on a willingness to get attention. and collect a drove of subordinates.

Comment: Try to change the direction of the shadows so the light appears coming from the upper left. That is the most common way of depicting shadows.